# how to check Apple In-app purchase's transactionIDs for the app i developed in my merchant account?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-app purchase in my iOS application for subscription. can i see how many people have paid in-app purchase product and later asked for refunds. Can i see those in-app purchase's transactionID in my apple merchant account? so that i could manually stop services provided by my app server to those who have took refund and still using services in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in Apple support and as per their answer, what i understood is, 
 - Apple does not provide customer or refund information to developers.
 - we can do Receipt Validation which will have Cancellation Date if user has got refund. which we can use in our application to check if any user have got the refund.

- check given below links :

Receipt Validation : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573

Receipt Fields :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1)